# Can't import Three.js into Vue with modules

Tags: webpack, vue.js, three.js

I'm using Three.js with Vue through Webpack and trying to use TrackballControl.js from within the example folder of the npm [three module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three). I've been reading how to best go about it and discovered [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9562#issuecomment-383390251) solution on Github.

[image]

So configured my code on that and have interpreted this as creating a file called three.js. With the following code:

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
global.THREE = THREE;

require('three/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls');

module.exports = global.THREE;
```

And importing it like this in my component:

```
import * as THREE from './three'
```

However now I'm receiving the warnings of

> "export 'TrackballControls' (imported as 'THREE') was not found in
>   './three'
>
> "export 'WebGLRenderer' (imported as 'THREE') was not found in
>   './three'
>
> "export 'Scene' (imported as 'THREE') was not found in './three'
>   ...

Where have I gone wrong, any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Webpack with Three and Vue and for GLTFLoader and for me this works:

```
import {GLTFLoader, GLTF} from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader"
```